# Rails - form_tag not able to perform post action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to rails and I have the following form in my application, but for some reason I'm not able to perform a post request with this form. However, the get request does change the route, but for post request, it just disables the submit button on click. Can anyone assist me with this, and also let me know the reason?

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_tag(reviews_path, method: :post, class: 'form-horizontal') do %>
      <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <%= select(:review, :rating, options_for_select([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]], 5), {}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8">
            <%= text_field(:review, :review_comment, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Review') %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <%= submit_tag 'Post Review', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when you attempt to perform the POST request. Are you seeing any errors in the browser or the Rails log? Can you tell if the request is hitting your ReviewsController? We'll be better able to help with more details.

Comment: Have you tried giving the action as a string? `method: "post"`. Also are you sure you're submitting to the right path? `reviews_path` probably corresponds with the index action which isn't usually where you want to submit forms

Comment: The best way for us to help you debug this (and for you to learn how to debug) is for you to have a look at the rails log. Either look at the scrolling text in the terminal where you have `rails server` running, or look in the log-file: `log/development.log`. Hit the submit button, and see what appears in the console/log-file. Then copy the text that appears and edit your question and add it there so we can see (then comment here so we know you've done it). Copy all the text that appeared * after * you hit "submit" - we'll help you read the relevant parts.

Comment: @TarynEast Development log says it all. I haven't added any redirection or a render hence I wasn't seeing anything happening. Thanks.